# jQuery Data table is very slow with request to Server Side

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used jQuery DataTable in my site that displays all the products list for our clients, I am currently using jQuery DataTable plugin for pagination, searching and sorting. It works fine except one problem Data Loading is very slow. It loads 8000's of rows from the sql database and populates the table.

Here my code

```
if($('#product-liste').length) {
    jQuery('#product-list').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search",
            "sProcessing": "Processing...",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Processing...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
            "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "First",
                "sLast":  "Last",
                "sNext":  "Next",
                "sPrevious": "Previous"
            }
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": window.location.href,
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "year" },
            { "data": "type" },
            { "data": "slug" }
        ],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        initComplete: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: loading 8K records will hang the UI, better use pagination from server side

Comment: try to use server side paggination here is example http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/ loading all records at once is really a bad idea

Comment: Don't load more than 150-200 records at once in to the browser in to scrollable tables. Otherwise it will use too much mem and will slowdown exponentially

Comment: Yes now i limit record 0-50 first load but data table still slow when request to server

Comment: Well, now that the question is about serverside perfomance, why not show that part instead of the clientside script? Seems somehow to have more relevance :)